# BeautifulSoup -- extracting both "td" objects without class (_class = None or False) and other class types

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrap from a website that has `td` objects. Some of those have no class, which I can extract with

`object.find_all("td", class_=None)`

And others have a class called `sem_dados`, which I can extract using

`object.find_all("td", class_="sem_dados")`

Main issue is: I can't do both at the same time. For instance,

`object.find_all("td", class_=[None, "sem_dados"])`

will not return the `td` objects that have no class. This seems to be a problem with the `None` or `False` behavior within a list, since

`object.find_all("td", class_=[None])`

Will also return an empty list.

Anyone knows how to change the syntax so I can call both together? The ordering of the extraction would be important. I could manually reorder, but I believe there must be a syntax to do what I am trying to do.

Tried many different syntaxes, but still couldn't get something working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use custom `lambda` function:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''\
<td class="sem_dados">I want this 1</td>
<td class="other">I don't want this</td>
<td>I want this 2</td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find_all('td', class_=lambda c: not c or 'sem_dados' == c))
```

Prints:

```
[<td class="sem_dados">I want this 1</td>, <td>I want this 2</td>]
```